# Hive - How can I stop logs displaying in console?

Tags: hive

I have been trying to omit logs from console while querying in hive, but still it is showing up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening the hive console by typing

```
> hive
```

in your terminal and then write queries, you can solve this by simply using

```
> hive -S
```

This basically means that you are starting hive in silent mode.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the polling interval to minutes or hours:

```
SET hive.exec.counters.pull.interval=[millis];
```

The default is 1000 milliseconds, but you can increase it to anything you like. That should decrease the number of logs written to stdout.

Comment: It does not work for me. I have been running everything (Hadoop, hive etc) on windows (just for the sake of learning).  I have tried everything like changing log level to error; I guess I have missed something in hive-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any logs on the console while starting the shell you can set the `hive.root.logger` property

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --config hive.root.logger=INFO,DRFA
```

> `hive.root.logger` **specifies the logging level as well as the log
>   destination**. Specifying console as the target sends the logs to the
>   standard error (instead of the log file).

If you want to see ERROR messages on console you can set this command

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --config hive.root.logger=ERROR,console
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I have tried changing the log level to ERROR, but I can see logs in console.  I have been running hive on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Start hive in silent mode using

```
$ hive -S
```

then Set logger level to Error, which will avoid Warnings/Info from printing.

```
hive> set logger.PerfLogger.level = ERROR;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings." in your log, it means that there are multiple log4j jars (different versions, different behaviors) in the class path

I don't know the principle of log4j, but according to the Hadoop configuration file, perform the following steps:

```
cd $HIVE_HOME/conf

cat > log4j.properties <<EOL
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, CA

log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
EOL
```

After starting hive (Hive 3.1.2 Apache), the log is set to WARN level, which may not necessarily work, but you can try it.